# Printing \r to STDOUT in PHP's CLI breaks after some time

Tags: php, linux, windows, command-line-interface, newline

I am running a PHP script from the command line. I access the linux server with PHP 5.3.3 (old version, I know) remotely, from a Windows 10 machine with putty. To keep track of what is happening I print and overwrite some data with a pseudo-newline (don't know what it's actually called); something like this:

```
fwrite(STDOUT, "$incrementingVar of $staticVar, $diffVar to go\r");
```

This line would be called a couple of times per minute.

When launching the script, everything works fine: each line is over-written in the command line interface. However, after some time suddenly the `\r` seems to have changed to `\n` because each line is written on a new line in the command line. As you can imagine, this is incredibly annoying behaviour. Is this a bug/glitch, or is there something in my output script that should be improved?

Comment: In addition to the answer, you might want to `trim()` the vars in case one of them has a newline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You line might become to long, so the `carriage return` (`\r`) will only return to the begin of the next line and not the previous line; try to make you PuTTY-Window larger.